autofit column width by content ignoring header in ag-grid-vue3
I am using the ag-grid-vue3 library in a vue app, and I want to shrink the width of the grid for just to show the full text inside it, ignoring the width of the header, like if the content of the grid is shorter than the content of the header, the whole width will be affected by the width of the grid. I´ve read the docs about different ways of doing this but none works (in my case). Then I tried to use css and the closest I´ve been of what I want is by making the width of the .ag-header-cell class equal to cero, like this:
div.ag-header-cell-label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
div.ag-header-cell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 0;
}
div.ag-cell-value {
    padding: 0;
}

but this is too much. (It´s too much because the content of the grid is trimmed as well)
So my question is if  is there a way of achieving what I want with code or css?
